# Python selenium webdriver click functionality

Tags: python, selenium, click, webdriver

Does anyone know how you can click on a link based on the href using the python webdriver bindings. In `waitr-webdriver` you can do something like this:

```
browser.link(:href => "http://www.testsite.com/pageOne.html").click
```

But I haven't be able to find a similar function in the python webdriver. All there is are

`find_element_by_class_name`
`find_element_by_css_selector`
`find_element_by_id`
`find_element_by_link_text`
`find_element_by_name`
`find_element_by_partial_link_text`
`find_element_by_tag_name`
`find_element_by_xpath`

These are great methods but the site I am testing has no ID's or Classes in their links. So the only unique thing about the links are the href url.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under the covers, watir-webdriver is converting the call to find the link where the href attribute is a given value into a WebDriver find-by-XPath expression. Mimicing this in your own code, the appropriate way to handle this in Python would be:

```
# assume driver is an instance of WebDriver
# NOTE: this code is untested
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[@href='http://www.testsite.com/pageOne.html']")
```

Alternatively, you could use CSS selectors (which would be faster on IE) as follows:

```
# again, assume driver is an instance of WebDriver
# NOTE: this code is untested
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[href='http://www.testsite.com/pageOne.html']")
```

Comment: Thanks you. I think this will help greatly.